# Decimal precision in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have a problem in Odoo 9 Community Edition, I changed the decimal accuracy of the database fields to 3 as stated to below
[image]
And also the rounding in Accounting/Currencies. Everything works fine only in these two interfaces:

1: Sales orders interface

[image]

2: A sale order

[image]

The good thing is that in invoicing, everything is fine:

1: Client Invoices

[image]

2: An invoice

[image]

Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Odoo 9, all the fields related to amount have changed the field type to "Monetary". Most of them are formatted using widget="monetary". In order for it to work according to the currency setting, "currency_id" field is required. Hence "currency_id" field must be included in the view. For example, in sale.order.form view

```
. . .
<tree string="Sales Order Lines" editable="bottom" decoration-info="invoice_status=='to invoice'">
    . . .
    <field name="price_subtotal" widget="monetary"/>
    <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>           <!-- Add this line -->
    . . .
</tree>
```

The subtotal will then be formatted according to the currency of the sales order.

Answer (score 1):

You go to Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy then change what you want !

Comment: That's what I did in the first screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Odoo 14 Answer: If you want to find the "Technical" menu mentioned above, you have to enable the "Developer mode"
In order to enable it => Go in the Setting menu scroll at the end of the general settings screen. You'll find some links that will enable developer mode and then the Technical menu will appear.